# Showing that $x^3 - t$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I was reading the post [Is $\mathbb{F}_3(t,t^{1/3})/\mathbb{F}_3(t)$ a normal extension? Is it separable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434775/is-mathbf-f-3t-t1-3-mathbf-f-3t-a-normal-extension-is-it-separable)

I do not understand, why we can use Eisenstein's criterion to show that $x^3 - t$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)[x]$. As far as I know, Eisenstein's criterion is specific to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and generalises by a lemma from Gauss to $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but not to finite fields or their extensions in general - am I wrong in saying so?

If we cannot use Eisenstein's criterion, what would be the best way to show that the polynomial is indeed irreducible?

Comment: A polynomial of degree $3$ (or $2$ as well) is irreducible iff it has no roots.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how can I use this fact, if I don't know what the degree of the extension $\mathbb{F}_3(t)/\mathbb{F}_3$ is? I would have to try all sorts of linear combinations (infinitely many) of the form $a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + a_3t^3 + a_4t^4 + \cdots$ as candidates for possible roots.

Comment: If $w = p/q \in \mathbb{F}_3(t)$ is a rational function, then $\deg(w^3) = 3\deg(p) - 3\deg(q) \neq 1 = \deg(t)$, hence no rational function can be a root of $X^3 - t$.

Comment: Do you mean that $p$ and $q$ are each polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_3(t)[x]$? I think I understand what you're saying :). What about Eisenstein's criterion though - am I right in saying that it cannot be used as claimed in the other post?

Comment: In the comment above $p$ and $q$ are elements of $\mathbb{F}_3[t]$, and the degree is understood with respect to variable $t$. 

As for the Eisenstein criterion, I haven't thought about it, but I think one could show that $X^3 - t$ is irreducible as a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_3[t]$. I think this is what the linked post meant. Note that Eisenstein criterion can be applied to polynomials with coefficients in any integral domain, not just $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh, ok. This helps a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, note that going from iredducibility over $\mathbb{F}_3[t]$ to irreducibility over $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$ involves Gauss lemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove $x^3 - t$ is irreducible, it suffices to show there are no roots thereof.

Recall that elements $z$ of $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$ are of the form $z = \frac{P(t)}{Q(t)}$ where $P, Q \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$ and $Q \neq 0$. We define $degree(z) = degree(P) - degree(Q)$ (you must verify that this is well defined).

Note that $degree$ is a monoid homomorphism $degree : (\mathbb{F}_3(t), \cdot) \to (\mathbb{Z} \cup \{-\infty\}, +)$.

Now if we had $z$ such that $z^3 = t$, then we would have $3 degree(z) = degree(t) = 1$. But there is no $k \in \mathbb{Z} \cup \{-\infty\}$ such that $3k = 1$.